# What does "as" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> We shall discuss the problem as it relates to our specific case.

What does "as" in this sentence mean? I searched a dictionary and found two alternative definitions. one is *in the way in which*; the other is the reason for doing something, “because” in short.

Usually, I can distinguish these two definitions, but in this case, I'm inclined to understand it with the meaning of because, like, the reason why we discuss the problem is because it concerns itself with our specific case, which makes perfect sense to me. However, the answer shows that the former definition is the right one, but why?

Comment: I'd say it's ambiguous between the two meanings you suggest. To emphasise reason, you could set off the _as_ expression with punctuation such as a comma.

Comment: What "answer" are you referring to in your last sentence?

Comment: @BillJ the answer is just a translation of my own language, I found it was different from what I expected.

Comment: The answer is wrong, As I said, it's ambiguous between a comparative PP and a reason adjunct, though a comma after "problem" would help disambiguate. Btw, "ambiguous" means there is more than one answer. You'll just have to accept that.

Comment: I don't think the sentence is ambiguous as all.  Yes, *as* can mean "because" (like in "I am very hungry, as I have had nothing to eat today") but in this context I cannot possibly see interpreting it that way, because "as it relates to"  is such a common stock phrase, always meaning "in the way that it relates to".

Comment: @stangdon So it is out of idiom, right?

Comment: @wonderfulwonder  I'm not sure what you mean by "out of idiom", but "as it relates to" is a very standard phrase that always means the same thing, yes.

Comment: @stangdon Doesn't "out of" mean "because" sometimes? Did I use it in the wrong way?

Comment: @wonderfulwonder  "Out of" means "originating from".  You could use it like "I washed the dishes *out of* a sense of responsibility", but it doesn't mean "because" in general.  The best way to say what you wanted would just be "So it's *idiomatic*, right?"

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more context for the sentence?

The first meaning of *as* is the most likely. This would make the sentence mean "We shall discuss those aspects of the problem that relate to our specific case".

It would be possible to understand *as* as meaning *because*, but the sentence would have to be

> We *shall* discuss the problem, as it relates to our specific case.

-- meaning that we would not have discussed it otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, there is no context to it.  So, regardless of the second meaning, what makes you think that the first one is the most likely? Are there some sort of mindsets or grammatical rules helping me understand this sentence in the way that "as" is used in the first meaning?

Comment: You mention an answer, so there must be _some_ context! As Bill J. says, and as I showed in my example, a comma would make the 'because' meaning certain.